# how to use the parameters exited in a method input in sql query commands?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

this is my code:

```
  public void addUser(int id,string username,string password,int 
   accountcredit)
    {
        SqlConnection sq1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User ID=xx;Password=xxxxxxx");
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("", sq1);
        command.CommandText = "insert into userData values(@id,@username,@password,@accountcredit) ";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountcredit", accountcredit);

        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(command.CommandText,sq1);

    }
```

the method "addUser()" is supposed to get id, username, password and account credit as arguments and add them to a table designed to keep records of users. I have tried to do that using the code above but I've noticed that I cannot simply use the method addUser() parameters in the SQL query. my question is how I should use the parameters of the method in the SQL query.  really 
I really appreciate your help guys.

Comment: `I've noticed that I cannot simply use the method addUser() parameters in the SQL query`  What do you mean by this?

Comment: You are not calling the ExecuteNonQuery method from the SqlCommand. Of course nothing is added to your table. And the SqlDataAdapter is not required here

Comment: As Steve says, you've just forgotten to execute the query. it's nothing to do with the parameters.

Comment: There is also another possible problem here. You are not listing the fields that will receive the parameters values. In this way you should be sure that you have inserted a value for every field in that table and none of your field has the IDENTITY property set to ON (ID?)

Comment: And please no `.AddWithValue` See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To consolidate some of the comments, you need to replace the redundant line

```cs
SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(command.CommandText,sq1);
```

with

```cs
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This should execute the query you've constructed against your database.